# How to attach a User Profile Photo from my computer and not a http:// address?

Tags: user-profile

I'm trying to add profile photos to my users on Insight and the only way I see how to do it is provide a website address where it has to be pulled form.
I don't have photos saved on different websites, they are stored on my computer. Is there a way to add the profile photo from my pc?
Please see attached photo with a detailed example.
Thanks so much, I appreciate your help.

Brooke[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think best option is upload the pictures into the site in a picture library from your computer then reference the picture from that URL.